# I run quick installation command for project setup it is show me this error in magento 2.3.6?

Tags: magento2.3.6

I am install Magento 2.3.6 project
I run quick installation command and this show me given error below.

[image]

Comment: Did you run the installation on an existing or fresh database?

Comment: i am run fresh database but this error show @Hoargarth

Comment: Sorry but I can't find the `completecatalog` table or view in any of my Magento2 projects. Is this some custom installation? Or an existing project you are reinstalling? Can you give us more information?